# Function with if else condition in javascript ever returns true

Tags: javascript

I have the function below:

```
$("#botao").on("click", function(){
    s = $("#municipio").val();
    alert(s);
    if (s == 1){
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://gatolovers.com.br/uf/popup1.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Uhul! Nós atendemos sua região. Temos uma unidade de atendimento pertinho de você. Ligue agora mesmo e faça um orçamento.');
    }else{
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://gatolovers.com.br/uf/popup0.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Ops! Ainda não estamos na sua cidade. Mas muito em breve levaremos a melhor empresa de Redes de Proteção para sua região, consulte nosso plano de expansão.');
    }
});
```

Independs of `s` be 0 or 1, the function ever return the first block.

The problem are the div `#mensagem` and `#imagem` that not work correctly. The admin can delete this post.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem in the `if` check. JS seems to be parsing well even if the `s` is string and has spaces. I would suggest to put alert inside the `if` and `else` block to see if something else is causing a problem.

Comment: Probably OP means `Independs of s be 0 or 1, the function always return the first block.` Correct me if this is not what you mean.

Comment: Unrelated, but as a matter of semantics, neither block explicitly returns anything. Check your assumptions, because it's likely the code is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao is this

Comment: @SubirKumarSaoI put alert into blocks and detect that execute the correct block but the text is not changing. thanks

Comment: I would then check if the elements with id exists in the dom. And only one element with the id exists. `imagem` and `mensagem`. Also check console if you are getting any error message.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao it's works. thanks

Comment: Post what was the actual problem and what solved it. @ItaloRodrigo

Answer (score 3):

> Try with replacing your if condition as : if(s===1)

```
$("#botao").on("click", function(){
    s = $("#municipio").val();
    alert(s);
    if (s === 1){
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://gatolovers.com.br/uf/popup1.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Uhul! Nós atendemos sua região. Temos uma unidade de atendimento pertinho de você. Ligue agora mesmo e faça um orçamento.');
    }else{
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://gatolovers.com.br/uf/popup0.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Ops! Ainda não estamos na sua cidade. Mas muito em breve levaremos a melhor empresa de Redes de Proteção para sua região, consulte nosso plano de expansão.');
    }
});
```

Comment: The strong check might be a problem as I suspect `s` is a string. Anyways OP has confirmed `if` check is executing as expected.